# React Native split image into binary chunks

Tags: javascript, react-native, file-upload, binary-data

Is it possible in react native to split an image into binary chunks? If so what is the method of doing so. I am using the CameralRoll API to get filepaths to images on the user's phone.

We want to upload images to our server in chunks using multipart form data.

Comment: Available soon: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-split-file  :-)